# Configure a multi-tenant Azure application

Tags: azure, web-applications, powerbi, multi-tenant

I created the Azure multi-tenant application through the Application Registration for Power BI (https://dev.powerbi.com/apps) in a company tenant 7/9. It works fine, I can use it from other organizations' tenants.
On 7/30, I created another multi-tenant application in the same tenant company with the same configuration as the previous one. And the last application sends me an error:

[image: error description]

I don't understand why one of these applications works well and the other doesn't. Are there any restrictions on multi-tenant applications? Have there been updates to the MS policy within two weeks between application creation dates?

P.S.

1. I use the same user account to get access in both cases
2. I don't use any permissions that require administrator's approval at all

Thanks!

Comment: Hi，If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to your error description, you need to use the application to access the resources protected by the administrator in Azure, but you are logged in to a normal user account, so he will prompt you with this error message.

You should first log in to the tenant administrator account and grant this permission to the administrator to consent, and then you will no longer have an error prompt if you switch to a normal account.

As for why the application you created before does not have this prompt,I guess it is because you have logged in to the administrator account before and granted all permissions to the administrator consent. But you may have recently created a new application and added permissions, so he will prompt you to log in to the administrator account to grant the administrator consent.

**Update :**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I used the same user account for authorization in both cases, so I do not know why this was enough for the first application and not enough for the second.

Comment: @Liza  Yes, for some permissions, the administrator’s consent is indeed not required, but for those permissions that require the administrator’s consent, you need to log in with the administrator account and grant the consent of the administrator. For those permissions that require the administrator’s consent, you You can go to `Azure portal`>`App registrations`>`API permissions`>`Admin consent required` to view .

Comment: I know about permissions that require administrator's approval, but I didn't include such permissions at all.